# Tools that can used with Geb & Spock framework for windows based application testing?

Tags: automated-tests, spock, geb

I wanted to know if we can use Geb and spock framework for windows application automation testing? If yes, then please suggest the suitable tools that can be used with Geb & Spock framework for windows application automation testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to test a web application deployed on windows with Spock/Geb, then yes you can!

You can test any web application regardless of its language (php, python, ruby whatever)

Start reading the Geb manual at http://www.gebish.org/

If you mean a normal windows desktop application, then no you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a Windows Desktop application, using Page Object Patterns, take a look at [Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx)

Geb is nothing more than a very nice wrapper around Web Driver, you can only automated web browser interactions.